# What is the meaning of "komuna" and how is it different from "ofta"?

Tags: word-meaning

In English, we often use *common* for the adjective equivalent of *often*. But in Esperanto, the word "ofta" already exist. Does that mean *komuna* has a different meaning than in English?

Answer (score 4):

"Komuna" basically means "shared", whereas "ofta" means "frequent". The most common translation for "common" or "usual" is "kutima".

Answer (score 3):

The word *common* in English has multiple possible meanings. *Komuna* and *ofta* can both be translated to "common" in English, but "common" can be translated to one or both, depending on the context.

- *Ofta* refers to things that aren't unusual. A better translation in English might be "commonplace". For example, one might say: *"Facilaj demandoj estas oftaj en StackExchange."* The adverbial form, *ofte*, while usually translated as *often*, can then be thought of as describing an action as commonplace.
- *Komuna* refers to things which are communal or shared by more than one person or group. The best equivalent I can think of in English is a "common border." One might say that *"StackExchange estas komuna demandejo."*